# Syntax highlighting glitches in iOS app on comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, ios-app

I've recently noticed that the iOS app glitches in some cases where it highlights correctly only parts of the comment.

Some examples:
[image: glitch]
[image]

[Link to question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626355/1348195)

Comment: I've noticed it too. It seems to only properly highlight the visible area, and doesn't affect the overflow

Comment: might be nice to add links to those posts in order to reproduce

Comment: @mhlester sorry, but how do I get a link from within the app or open one? Also, the "only visible" observation seems to be spot on!

Comment: click the sideways ellipsis next to the timestamp of the post, tap **Share**, then **Copy**

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Done.

Comment: Needs more [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/246931) for those of us who don't know how it's supposed to look! And also for science reasons in general. Also, I'd tack on the [tag:comments] tag while you're at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will (possibly) be fixed in the next build.  I saw the problem, implemented a possible fix, and then didn't the problem.  Is it fixed?  Maybe.

For context, this is a `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` bug.  The HTML and CSS are 100% correct.  You can tell because if you tap the code and see the popup, all I did was rip the post-prettified innerHTML and crammed it into another web view.

My fix(?) was to move that declaration to a new rule that is only set after prettify is called:

```
<style>
.touchEnabled pre { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
</style>

<script>
prettyPrint();
document.body.className += ' touchEnabled';
</script>
```

The neat thing, and the part that fills me with a little confidence about this fix is that I stuck in some obligatory `background-color: green;` stuff and when the web view loaded I saw the color change take place, so rendering is definitely delayed.

Comment: ooh i hope you kept the green there for us

Comment: @mhlester *frantically rerunning the build to make sure I didn't*